# Moving SVN controlled project up one folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I have a Visual Studio project that is version controlled with SVN.  The local working copy is at `C:\ProjectName\SolutionName` and the repository is at `//servername/svn/ProjectName` (with the **SolutionName** folder within that).

The problem is that in the working folder, only the **SolutionName** folder is checked out.  I now have sibling folders such as `C:\ProjectName\Database` and `C:\ProjectName\Documentation` that I need to add to SVN.  I can add these folders directly to the repository and check them out individually, but what I would like to do is move the "checked out" portion up one level, so that everything within `C:\ProjectName` is under version control.  This would make it easier to do commits (all from one folder, instead of needing multiple commits for each folder).  It would also make it easier to add new folders to the source control in the future.

Is there an easy way to do this?  The one method I came up with is to unversion my working copy then delete and recreate the repository with it set up the way I want.  The project is recent enough that it wouldn't be a huge problem to lose the 20-or-so commit history in there, but I was hoping for a more straightforward way to do it.

---

*In case it helps:* I am using TortoiseSVN for most of my transactions, but I have command line tools installed as well.  I also have direct access to the server hosting my repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, import your new local folders to svn:

- C:\ProjectName\Database -> //servername/svn/ProjectName/Database
- C:\ProjectName\Documentation -> //servername/svn/ProjectName/Documentation

Now, your layout *on the server* looks the way you want it.

Next, simply check out a *new* working copy of //servername/svn/ProjectName (perhaps in C:\src\ProjectName).  This will give you the structure you want in your working copy (three folders: Database, Documentation, and SolutionName).  Then, simply abandon your "old" working copy (at C:\ProjectName).  If you like, you can delete the C:\ProjectName folder, and copy C:\src\ProjectName to C:\ProjectName if it is important to maintain that current folder (you are allowed to "move" entire working copies like this locally).

The beauty of source control is that it's easy to move your "local copy" around, since the *real* code is on the server.

Comment: **New WC** is overkill - `svn up` will play the game: I'm sure OP didn't use --depth option

Comment: I think the OP only had the one subfolder (SolutionName) checked out as his current working copy.  He wants to have the ProjectName folder checked out.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I misread and thought about SolutionName as root with *two new nodes below*

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, if you were to check out the repository, you would see the `SolutionName` folder within the directory. (Meaning the folder, not just the contents, is under version control.)

If that's correct, try this:

1. Check out the project into a new folder (say `C:\ProjectName_Temp`).
2. Copy your folders from `C:\ProjectName` to `C:\ProjectName_Temp`.
3. Remove the `.svn` folder from `C:\ProjectName_Temp\SolutionName`. (Don't remove `C:\ProjectName_Temp\.svn`).
4. Rename your original folder to, say, `C:\ProjectName_bak` as a backup (in case I'm wrong, so you don't lose anything) and rename the `_Temp` folder to `C:\ProjectName\`.

From there, check `svn status` (or Tortoise's equivalent command) and make sure all of the changes are expected.

I hope this helps!